# class names in React production

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app, styled-components

I am using create-react-app-2, I've recently deployed my app to production (building the react app using npm run build).

I have a number of issues/questions.

1. My class names are being converted to a form jssxxx. Can you tell me why this is, and which part of the create-react-app is responsible for this? The css-loader?

[image]

2. I'm styling material UI with styled components, and sometimes my styles aren't applied. Where would one start when debugging this in production?

BTW, all the styles seem to be applied in development.

Comment: styled components creates classNames for you. If you are wrapping the material-ui in `styled-components`, I would bet that would contribute. Although I have never seen them use the jss prefix. Normally they use sc-xxxxxx

Comment: perhaps they are using this package internally. https://cssinjs.org/?v=v9.8.7

Comment: There are several issues that could contribute here. The `jss` class names are coming from the JSS class name generator that material-ui is using. It is possible that you are splitting your code in a way that two instances of this class name generator are being used that are producing conflicting names. For more information: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-aren-39-t-my-components-rendering-correctly-in-production-builds

Also make sure that you are not mixing imports for the material-ui main module and the `/es` module, this would mix stylings as well.